# CMake equivalent of GNU make's --directory (-C)

Tags: cmake, command-line-interface

I am wondering if there is a *CMake* command line interface option, which does the same as `--directory` (`-C`) for GNU *make*?

What I want to do is to tell *CMake* to generate the build files in the source directory, **not** in *CWD*.

---

The quick and dirty way of doing this could be:

```
cd path/to/source && cmake . && make && make install
```

however, there must be a better way.

I was considering

```
cmake --build "path/to/source"
```

but that requires the build files to be present, and

```
cmake . -E chdir "path/to/source"
```

dumps the build files in *CWD*, just like:

```
cmake /path/to/source
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CMake is a build system generator and it is not a replacement for make, your question does not make a lot of sense.

But the described behavior can be achieved. CMake has the options -H and -B to specify the source and binary directory, but they are undocumented. In your case this would be

```
cmake -Hpath/to/source -Bpath/to/source && cmake --build path/to/source
```

Comment: For those who somehow wander into this question, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712020/changing-cmake-files-standard-location) is essentially the same, but much more elegantly phrased.