# How to setup make options with cmake

Tags: cmake

I would like to setup commands like `make debug`, `make test`, etc... What is the best way to do this with cmake, so that I run `cmake ..` one time (it takes a while) and then be able to choose the build type with `make`?

I couldn't find any resources on this.

Comment: On CMake **build type** is choosen on **configuration** stage (`cmake ..` invocation). Exception is *multiconfiguration* build systems, but make isn't count as such.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [How to speed up Compile Time of my CMake enabled C++ Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327526/how-to-speed-up-compile-time-of-my-cmake-enabled-c-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev has commented this needs a little extra work for [single-configuration environments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html?highlight=single%20configuration) (respectively CMake's [Makefile generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#makefile-generators)) since the build type is chosen during CMake's configuration and finalized during the build environment generation step.

So here is what I've done:

- First you run - e.g. in a script - CMake for all configurations you want to support and choose respective sub-folders for the output:

  ```
  > cmake -H"." -B"Debug" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
  > cmake -H"." -B"Release" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
  ```

  *Note*: `-H` (for "home directory") and `-B` (for "binary output directory") are [undocumented options](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Documenting-the-H-and-B-options-td7593171.html), but very useful in those cases. And they work with all CMake releases so far. Just be careful not to put spaces between the option and the their values.
- Then you can use again CMake to build from/in those sub-folders:

  ```
  > cmake --build "Debug" 
  > cmake --build "Release"
  ```
- And if you want to run the tests you can:

  ```
  > cmake --build "Debug" --target "test"
  > cmake --build "Release" --target "test"
  ```

**References**

- [Changing CMake files standard location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712020/changing-cmake-files-standard-location)
- [Does CMake always generate configurations for all possible project configurations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091010/does-cmake-always-generate-configurations-for-all-possible-project-configuration)
- [cmake build multiple targets in different build directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999130/cmake-build-multiple-targets-in-different-build-directories)
- [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE not being used in CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460486/cmake-build-type-not-being-used-in-cmakelists-txt)