# Telling CMake change the cache location but not Makefile

Tags: makefile, build, cmake

According to the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712020/#13713684), I can tell CMake to use use `phantom-dir`
 to place cache files in it by using

```
cmake -H. -Bphantom-dir
```

However, I need three further customization:

- The `Makefile` should be created inside in the current directory not `phantom-dir`.
- The executable output of `Makefile` should be in the current directory too.
- I need that `-H. -Bphantom-dir` be embedded in `CMakeLists.txt` hence a typical user will call cmake in the normal way by `cmake .`

Are these customizations implementable?

Comment: No, I wouldn't create such a system. It might break with every new CMake release. You could atchieve the last point by calling CMake yourself with execute_process, but that has so many disadvantages.

Comment: @usr1234567: So, are we destined to tolerate a lot of messy files on the current directory?

Comment: No, always use a build directory and you are set.

Comment: @usr1234567, the build directory does not have access to the resource files unless it uses `../`

Comment: That's a question of its own.