Run profiling (-fprofile-arcs) in cmake
It is quite simple to do in a standard makefile

GOVFLAGS= -lgov

# Library has been build, all objectfiles are left in build directory
timings: benchmark/timings.c $(LIBNAME)
    # compile benchmark/timings.c, link it with all objectfiles
    # and put executable in build directory
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(GOVFLAGS) -o timings

profiling:
    # Call makefile again with additional flag "-fprofile-arcs"
    # to generate the *gcda files while making the benchmark function
    make CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS) -fprofile-arcs" timings
    # run the "before" benchmark
    ./timings
    # remove static library and objectfiles. *gcda files stay, of course
    rm -f *.a *.o timings
    # Call makefile again with additional flag "-fbranch-probabilities"
    # to build the library with the actual optimizations.
    make CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS) -fbranch-probabilities"
        # snipped: part of benchmarking that builds and runs the "after"
    # benchmark


I was not able to find a method to call cmake recursively like make as shown above. I tried to do it by hand but I was not able to find a way to keep the *gcda files because I found no way to the same thing twice, as is needed for this method of profiling, and different targets compile in different sub-directories.
Another problem: its legacy code, so I have to take what is there, no changes in project structure (e.g. moving directories around etc.).
The build uses a separate directory for building (as in mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. -DOPTIONS=ARGS).
No modern cmake cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10) available.
How can I call cmake from within CMakeLists.txt to translate the above makefile snippet into a working cmake-script?
Alternative solutions are welcome, too, of course, I am fully aware of the risk that it might be an XY problem!
EDIT: this is what I have so far:
#snip
if(BUILD_PROFILE)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fprofile-arcs")
endif()
# snip
if(BUILD_PROFILE)
    # build "timing" from "demo/timing.c"
    add_executable(timing demo/timing.c)
    target_compile_options(timing BEFORE PRIVATE -DMP_VERSION=\"before\" )
    target_link_libraries(timing PRIVATE ${PROJECT_NAME})
    add_custom_command(TARGET timing POST_BUILD 
        COMMAND timing WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
    # rebuild libtommath with  -fprofile-arcs
    add_custom_command(TARGET timing POST_BUILD
        COMMAND make clean && cmake .. -DBUILD_PROFILE_SECOND_RUN=ON  -DBUILD_PROFILE=OFF  && make)
# rebuild libtommath with  -fbranch-probabilities
elseif(BUILD_PROFILE_SECOND_RUN)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fbranch-probabilities")
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD 
        COMMAND cmake .. -DBUILD_PROFILE_SECOND_RUN=OFF  -DBUILD_PROFILE=OFF  -DBUILD_PROF_CMP=ON  && make)
# Run timings over profiled library and run gnuplot over the logs
elseif(BUILD_PROF_CMP)
    find_program(GNUPLOT gnuplot)
    # Rebuild "timing" from "demo/timing.c" against the profiled library
    add_executable(timing demo/timing.c)
    target_compile_options(timing BEFORE PRIVATE -DMP_VERSION=\"after\" )
    target_link_libraries(timing PRIVATE ${PROJECT_NAME})
    # TODO: write the CMakeLists.txt in logs and do it properly
    add_custom_command(TARGET timing POST_BUILD
        COMMAND  timing WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} 
        # ("timing" writes its tables in the "log" directory) Plot pictures with version
        COMMAND cd ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/logs && ${GNUPLOT} -c before_after.dem ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        # back to build directory
        COMMAND cd ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} 
    )
endif()
#snip


Here PROJECT_NAME is the main library to be build and profiled.
Yes, I am aware that it is an abomination for every expert but I hope it makes my intent a bit clearer.

Unlike to Make, CMake doesn't allow to change compiler options when build the project. That is, lines make CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS) -fprofile-arcs" timings and make CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS) -fbranch-probabilities" should be translated to different configurations of a CMake project. "How can I call cmake from within CMakeLists.txt - via execute_process or via add_custom_command.

You would first configure your cmake with the required compile options and then run the compilation.
cmake -S. -Bbuild -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fprofile-arcs
cmake --build build

I do not like the idea of rm -f *a storing files in your source files. Your profiling could look like the following:
_build:
    cmake -S. -Bbuild/$(BUILD) -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}
    cmake --build build/$(BUILD)

profiling:
    $(MAKE) _build BUILD=profile-arcs CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fprofile-arcs
    ./timings
    $(MAKE) _build BUILD=branch-probabilities CMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fbranch-probabilities
    # benchmark

But sure you could remove the $(BUILD) variable above and keep one build directory and rebuild everything every time.

How can I call cmake from within CMakeLists.txt to translate the above makefile snippet into a working cmake-script?

You can't - cmake does not translate makefiles into cmake-scripts.

Option -B (and -S ) is new in version 3.13 which is newer than the allowed minimum. Don't look at me that way, I did not make the rules, sorry!

Use -H instead of -S https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090821/what-does-the-h-option-means-for-cmake . It looks like you are right, so just mkdir && cd it.
